# How many training steps does it usually take to train an RL model?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, training, hyper-parameters, proximal-policy-optimization

This is my model average rewards as follow image.

How to tell if it is undertrained or not convergent? How many training steps does it usually take to train an RL model?

And I'm using [PPO](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/ppo.html) to train.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to know in advance precisely, only approximately, but it also strongly depends on the environment, hyperparameters and algorithm. For hard environments, e.g. the ones learning from pixels such as the Atari games, you can easily expect 1-10M steps.

You can get a feeling by looking at many solved environments, for instance here: https://github.com/Rafael1s/Deep-Reinforcement-Learning-Algorithms

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the the problem you're applying PPO to. To get an idea, you can have a look at the [CleanRL](https://docs.cleanrl.dev/) benchmarks, there are a few of them where they use PPO: https://wandb.ai/openrlbenchmark/openrlbenchmark/reportlist.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).